# Can I stay after P1 visa runs out?

Tags: visas, usa

Does anyone know if I can stay for four days after my P1 visa (USA) ends? Is there a 10 days grace period?

Comment: Are you in the US already? Or are you asking about a future trip?

Comment: It’s for a trip in January so not there yet.

Answer (score 1):

The US visa expiration date has no bearing on how long you are permitted to stay in the US. This is decided at the border by the immigration officer when you enter the country. Your stay can extend beyond the expiration date of the visa.

Normally on a P1 visa your initial entry should correspond approximately with the dates of the event(s) you are participating in. On a P1 visa [you can enter](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/214.2#p_12) up to 10 days before the start of your petition validity period, and you can leave at most 10 days after the end of the validity period.

Comment: Can the OP confirm the date by which they must leave the US (assuming that’s where they are now) by checking their I-94 record https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home?

Comment: I believe P1 are admitted from up to 10 days before the validity of the P1 petition to up to 10 days after the validity of the P1 petition. See 8 CFR 214.2(p)(12).

Comment: Thanks for this. So just make sure the immigration officer knows I want to stay longer  when I arrive there?

Comment: @Helen Yes, you can stay up to 10 days past the end of your petition validity period. Just let the immigration officer know your intended departure date if you are asked how long you are staying.